# Cassandra - How to model this use case?

Tags: database, model, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra, my question may be silly so please excuse me for that. I have a confusion on how to create the DB model for following use case. Using company-employee example for better understanding

1. There is a company having employees. One employee (may be senior) can work on different projects at the same time. In each project the employee has to perform different role ( software engineer, software tester, software designer, technical lead,architect, project manager, etc) due to seniority.
2. Also the employee's duration in each project (2 months, 4 months, 3 weeks, etc) is different. The employee's working hours are different in each project (2 hrs/day, 1 hr/week, etc)
3. Now the **problem statement is** how can I model this use case. How can I store the data of employee working for different project with different role with different duration and different work hours? Can I fit this information in one row of a table or do I need to create multiple rows for that employee?

Please, if possible, give details.

Comment: have you tried something? What's really important in NoSQL is to make the table thinking on what query you will have to make. For example, if you need to find all senior employee, or all junior often, you might consider to use the category of employee as a partition key. If you want random access on employee, you might consider to have partition based on the first letter of a name (like "ben").

Comment: @Whitefret I have used company-employee analogy here, my real requirement is just similar but I cannot mention it here due to non-disclosure agreement. In my case, most often I will query employee details with all those options like "different project with different role with different duration and different work hours". I need this data whenever I query employee. So my question is can I store all that data in one table (column family)? If yes then can I put it in one row of employee and how? If not how many column families do I need to create? I want to avoid querying multiple tables.

Comment: if you just need to get all info from an employee, you could make a key/value store (I would recommand mongo or HBase for that). But if I understand correctly, you want some query like: "gives employees where project = "" and function= "" " and that is hard to do in NoSQL database alone. Do you have to make SQL like queries?

Comment: @Whitefret, yes I will make queries like given the company id give me all employees with all data related with that employee like "different project with different role with different duration and different work hours". No where clause but just a limit. The confusion here is if I make different column families then I will have to make those many queries and I am not sure if I can avoid those many queries.Can I make use of composite or multivalued attributes or super column family concept where all details of an employee are stored in one row rather than multiple rows for different attributes.

Comment: You can store map in cassandra cell, this means you could store anything with a key/value relation. The problem with NoSQL is that you need to know how to access your data to design your base. By having every information about an employee in a map makes it impossible to query, but maybe you don't need to query those information

Comment: @Whitefret Thanks for your time. I will think on it.

Comment: go see the free tutorial on datastax academy, I thought they were interesting

Comment: I think this can be modeled by using a PRIMARY KEY of (company_id, employee_id, project_id) with company_id being the partition key. This however will not allow to query all employees for a given project_id like Whitefret mentioned. Also the cluster can lopsided with having a partition key like company_id, but since you need the queries to be 'for a given company_id' I don't see a way around this

Comment: @iconnj Thank you for your suggestion. I have already implemented the way you suggested but it is under testing right now to see whether it is right approach or not